# Why is comparing floats inconsistent in Java?

Tags: java, floating-point

```
class Test{  
    public static void main(String[] args){  
        float f1=3.2f;  
        float f2=6.5f;  

        if(f1==3.2){
            System.out.println("same");  
        }else{
            System.out.println("different");  
        }
        if(f2==6.5){
            System.out.println("same");  
        }else{  
            System.out.println("different");  
        }
    }  
}
```

output:

```
different
same
```

Why is the output like that? I expected `same` as the result in first case.

Comment: f==3.2f is true, when dealing with constant value floating pointers the default type is double.

Comment: then what about second case

Comment: why down vote.please give me the reason for downvote

Comment: Maybe because the title is misleading. I thought I would find a question about how a `float` is different from a `double`.

Comment: @DrewR. Thank you .I updated it.

Comment: I don't understand. There are still no `double`s anywhere in your question. Why did you change the title?

Comment: @DrewR. the `3.2` and `6.5` are both doubles.

Comment: Removed salutation: "Thanks in advance....", please don't do it next time

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The difference is that 6.5 can be represented exactly in both float and double, whereas 3.2 can't be represented exactly in either type. and the two closest approximations are different.

An equality comparison between float and double first converts the float to a double and then compares the two. So the data loss.

---

You shouldn't ever compare floats or doubles for equality; because you can't really guarantee that the number you assign to the float or double is exact.

***This rounding error is a characteristic feature of floating-point computation***.

> Squeezing infinitely many real numbers into a finite number of bits
> requires an approximate representation. Although there are infinitely
> many integers, in most programs the result of integer computations can
> be stored in 32 bits.
>
> In contrast, given any fixed number of bits,
> most calculations with real numbers will produce quantities that
> cannot be exactly represented using that many bits. Therefore the
> result of a floating-point calculation must often be rounded in order
> to fit back into its finite representation. This rounding error is the
> characteristic feature of floating-point computation.

Check [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) for more!

Comment: why the second result is true

Comment: 6.5 = 6+1/2 = 6+2^-1 = 110.1(2) (exact). But 3.2 = 3 + 5^-1 so it cannot be represented by a finite fractional in binary. Only rational numbers that have only the base's prime factors in the deminator can be represented in that base

Answer (score 25):

They're both implementations of different parts of [the IEEE floating point standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point). A `float` is 4 bytes wide, whereas a `double` is 8 bytes wide.

As a rule of thumb, you should probably prefer to use `double` in most cases, and only use `float` when you have a good reason to. (An example of a good reason to use `float` as opposed to a `double` is "I *know* I don't need that much precision and I need to store a million of them in memory.") It's also worth mentioning that it's hard to prove you don't need `double` precision.

Also, when comparing floating point values for equality, you'll typically want to use something like `Math.abs(a-b) < EPSILON` where `a` and `b` are the floating point values being compared and `EPSILON` is a small floating point value like `1e-5`. The reason for this is that floating point values rarely encode the exact value they "should" -- rather, they usually encode a value very close -- so you have to "squint" when you determine if two values are the same.

**EDIT**: Everyone should read the link @Kugathasan Abimaran posted below: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic for more!](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: why the second result is true

Comment: both answersare ok.sorry i can not accept morethan 1 answer.so +1 for u

Comment: No worries! I think @Kugathasan Abimaran probably gave the better answer anyway. :)

Answer (score 5):

To see what you're dealing with, you can use [Float](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#toHexString(float)) and [Double](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toHexString(double))'s toHexString method:

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("3.2F is: "+Float.toHexString(3.2F));
        System.out.println("3.2  is: "+Double.toHexString(3.2));
        System.out.println("6.5F is: "+Float.toHexString(6.5F));
        System.out.println("6.5  is: "+Double.toHexString(6.5));
    }
}
$ java Test
3.2F is: 0x1.99999ap1
3.2  is: 0x1.999999999999ap1
6.5F is: 0x1.ap2
6.5  is: 0x1.ap2
```

Generally, a number has an exact representation if it equals A * 2^B, where A and B are integers whose allowed values are set by the language specification (and double has more allowed values).

In this case,
6.5 = 13/2 = (1+10/16)*4 = (1+a/16)*2^2 == 0x1.ap2, while
3.2 = 16/5 = ( 1 + 9/16 + 9/16^2 + 9/16^3 + . . . ) * 2^1 == 0x1.999. . . p1.
But Java can only hold a finite number of digits, so it cuts the .999. . . off at some point.  (You may remember from math that 0.999. . .=1.  That's in base 10.  In base 16, it would be 0.fff. . .=1.)

Answer (score 3):

```
class Test {  
  public static void main(String[] args) {  
    float f1=3.2f;  
    float f2=6.5f;  

    if(f1==3.2f)  
      System.out.println("same");  
    else  
      System.out.println("different");  

    if(f2==6.5f)  
      System.out.println("same");  
    else  
      System.out.println("different");  
    }  
  }
```

Try like this and it will work. Without 'f' you are comparing a floating with other floating type and different precision which may cause unexpected result as in your case.

Comment: Actually, without the `f`, it is a comparison between two floating types, only with different precision.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to compare values of type `float` and `double` directly.  Before the values can be compared, it is necessary to either convert the `double` to `float`, or convert the `float` to `double`.  If one does the former comparison, the conversion will ask "Does the the `float` hold the best possible `float` representation of the `double`'s value?"  If one does the latter conversion, the question will be "Does the `float` hold a perfect representation of the `double`'s value".  In many contexts, the former question is the more meaningful one, but Java assumes that all comparisons between `float` and `double` are intended to ask the latter question.

I would suggest that regardless of what a language is willing to tolerate, one's coding standards should absolutely positively forbid direct comparisons between operands of type `float` and `double`.  Given code like:

```
float f = function1();
double d = function2();
...
if (d==f) ...
```

it's impossible to tell what behavior is intended in cases where `d` represents a value which is not precisely representable in `float`.  If the intention is that `f` be converted to a `double`, and the result of that conversion compared with `d`, one should write the comparison as

```
if (d==(double)f) ...
```

Although the typecast doesn't change the code's behavior, it makes clear that the code's behavior is intentional.  If the intention was that the comparison indicate whether `f` holds the best `float` representation of `d`, it should be:

```
if ((float)d==f)
```

Note that the behavior of this is very different from what would happen without the cast.  Had your original code cast the `double` operand of each comparison to `float`, then both equality tests would have passed.

Answer (score 1):

In general is not a good practice to use the == operator with floating points number, due to approximation issues.

Answer (score 0):

6.5 can be represented exactly in binary, whereas 3.2 can't. That's why the difference in precision doesn't matter for 6.5, so `6.5 == 6.5f`.

To quickly refresh how binary numbers work:

```
100 -> 4

10 -> 2

1 -> 1

0.1 -> 0.5 (or 1/2)

0.01 -> 0.25 (or 1/4)
```

etc.

6.5 in binary: `110.1` (exact result, the rest of the digits are just zeroes)

3.2 in binary: `11.001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001101...` (here precision matters!)

A float only has 24 bits precision (the rest is used for sign and exponent), so:

3.2f in binary: `11.0011001100110011001100` (not equal to the double precision approximation)

Basically it's the same as when you're writing 1/5 and 1/7 in decimal numbers:

```
1/5 = 0,2
1,7 = 0,14285714285714285714285714285714.
```

Answer (score -1):

Float has less precision than double, bcoz float is using 32bits inwhich 1 is used for Sign, 23 precision and 8 for Exponent . Where as double uses 64 bits in which 52 are used for precision, 11 for exponent and 1for Sign....Precision is important matter.A decimal number represented as float and double can be equal or unequal depends is need of precision( i.e range of numbers after decimal point can vary).    Regards S. ZAKIR