# Graphics use the values 0.01f and 2f: what is this format?

Tags: java, android

In Android graphics values are used like `2f` and `0.01f`. What number format is this, and how can we find their decimal representation? Why is this format generally used for graphics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are floats. floats take less space then doubles .
A float is 4 bytes wide, whereas a double is 8 bytes wide.
This is the biggest difference.

float range is 1.40129846432481707e-45 to 3.40282346638528860e+38

double range is 4.94065645841246544e-324d to 1.79769313486231570e+308d

floats precision is enough for graphics.

So when we need precision we use doubles, else we can just use floats because they take less memory.

In my case I use floats only when I have to, like for android , many graphic methods are defined by floats parameters.

see [this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16627813/whats-the-difference-between-float-double-in-java)

Comment: but float variable can store the both values either 1.0f and 1.0 and both are equal , then why we use 1.0f .

Comment: yes this example : 1.0 and 1.0f. every float could be written in double, but not every double is writable in a float. I updated a little bit my answer .

Answer (score 3):

Those are float literals.

```
float f = 1.0f;
double d = 1.0;
```

Comment: why we use 1.0f instead of 1.0

Comment: Because 1.0 is treated (by default) as double by the compiler, you could however use `float f = (float) 1.0;` but it's easier to use `float f = 1.0f;`.