# Inaccuracy in value inputed

Tags: java

```
 public void Calculate(double value){
        int quarter, dime, nickel, remainder;
        value *= 100;
        System.out.println(value);
```

This is part of a simple coin counter program (I'm learning programming)--I have value set to 2.26 but found that I didn't get the desired answer, so I did   System.out.println(value) to pinpoint where I am not getting the value expected. With value =  2.26, I should get 226 but instead I get 225.99999999999997, which throws off the entire program.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: This answer may help you understand the "issue"
http://stackoverflow.com/a/4937591/1379371

Comment: Would you say BigDecimal is the  best way to deal with all rounding errors like the one I'm encountering? I don't want to use a solution that applies to an insignificant number of cases because I want to be able to rely on one solution to the same kind of problem every time I encounter it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `double`. Double stores many places after decimal in memory so 2.26 is an approximation of a value which is like 2.25999999...

You must round your results to two places of decimal for accurate value.

If you want to know how to round numbers refer to this answer [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java)

Comment: When I simply print the "value" inside the function,it gives 2.26. Why does not it give value like 2.259999 in this case? why it uses approximation only if I change the value by multiplying it by another number,say 10 or 100?

Comment: @pramithasdhakal `double a = 2.26;` means let `a` be the closest `double` to 2.26. When you print `a` you see 2.26 because there are no `double` values closer to to the decimal value 2.26. However the true value of `a` is actually less than 2.26, so when you multiply by 100 the answer is less than 226. Unlike 2.26, 226 can be represented as a double. So printing `a * 100` doesn't print `226` because the output `226` is reserved for printing the "real" 226.

Comment: Thanks... that was an pretty interesting explanation..

Answer (score 0):

You can add casting to float, then it works fine

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calculate ((float) 2.26);       
}

public static void Calculate(float value){
    int quarter, dime, nickel, remainder;
    value *= 100;
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

Comment: Please read through this question- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16627813/why-is-comparing-a-float-to-a-double-inconsistent-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

```
 public void Calculate(double value){
        int quarter, dime, nickel, remainder;
        value *= 100;
        System.out.println(round(value,0));
 }
```